# R-Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny application where a user can input a date through the shiny application to then to trigger an R script to leverage that date.
I was wondering how do you link the date input from shiny to be leverage in an R script?

```
function(input, output) {
  # You can access the value of the widget with input$date, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$date })
}
```

Comment: You could put your R script code into a function which takes the date as a parameter, or just rewrite the script to be a series of reactive functions within the Shiny application. What is it that you need the script to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput("date","Date:"),
    textOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderPrint({ 
        x <- input$date
        # script using x goes here
        paste("choice:",x[1],"to",x[2]) # example output
        })
}
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```